# Using jquery for simple parsing - problems with ressource loading

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm accessing an api that returns result formatted as HTML. This is really wonky, as all i want is the data. I'm left with a task of transforming/parsing the resulting HTML into plain data.

So my code goes something like this:

```
var htmlData = $('<div>').html(apidata);
var personData = htmlData.find('table.result tr');
```

While this works and I eventually end up with the data i need, jquery/browser is eager to help parse this `apidata` once i wrap it inside my div (i presume it's creating a dom element and the browser handles the rest) resulting in a lot of 404's. What happens is, the apidata contains href, src etc all pointing to external and internal data (images, ressources, scripts, etc). Once the data is wrapped inside the `<div>` the loading starts.

What can i do to stop the parsing of the links. I only want the dom structure loaded so i can use the jquery/sizzle query engine to get my data. I have no need for parsing/loading the referenced resources embedded in the `apidata`.

EDIT: I'm trying to avoid using regex or the like to parse. The whole idea of using jquery is easy and powerfull parsing of the html.

Comment: What's the format of your __response__?

Comment: The response is in json, but the data in the json is stored in a property called Html. That property is text, containing valid html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i ended up with a solution that lets me use jquery's dom parsing, but filtering the input/data with regex first. This way i keep the power of jquery and need only simple regex to filter out data.

I found that only image source was loaded and not href on anchor tags - which makes good sense - so i ended up replacing the apidata like this:

```
var dom = $('<div>').html(htmlData.replace(/<img[^>]+\>/ig, ""));
```

And i can still query the dom like usual without getting all the 404's.